# How to take screenshot of an Outlook.com email message?

Tags: email, html-email, outlook.com

With Gmail, you could print the message which opens a new window with just the email message, then you can use any screenshot Chrome extension to capture the entire page.

However Outlook.com messages are always in a frame(?) and screenshot tools can't scroll through the message. How would you save the email to an image file this way?
[image: outlook.com email message]

Answer (score 1):

1. You can also use the print option in Outlook, and save as a PDF. 
   In the message preview, the three dots on the far right gives you a print version.
   Only limitation here is it could mess with the design a little.
2. In the same three dots, mentioned above, there is also an option 'Open in a new window.' This isn't really the best solution as it annoyingly opens a popup, rather than another tab. This disadvantage here is that it doesn't allow you to use any screenshot browser extensions.
3. By far the best option is to use the 'Open in browser' link, if supplied in the email template. But obviously, not everyone is as helpful as that so it may not be an option supplied by the sender.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes opening in a browser only gives you a text document, not full HTML.  However, you can ctrl + C to copy the full email and the ctrl + V to paste it into a blank Microsoft Word Document and then save as a PDF.

I have MS Outlook 2016 and it does not give me the option to save as a PDF from the print file.